# The int wont change to anything except 0

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a function that changes the cout and the cin without copy pasting the code but when I try to use it, it always input 0

```
void enterdata(string data, int data2) // Inputing datas
{
    cout << "Please Enter your ";
    cout << data.c_str() << endl;
    cin >> data2;
}
void input1() // Saving/Creating New
{
    system("cls");
    enterdata("Mobile Number", number);
    cout << "Your number is " << number << endl;
}
```

Comment: Pass number as reference like this `void enterdata(string data, int& data2)`. This is because data2 is a function parameter in which you are taking input, but it is call by value, so actual variable `number` wont get changed and you will get some default or garbage value.

Comment: omg thank you so much it was so simple

Comment: Since the suggested answers are correct, but enterdata can be improved more with `void enterdata(string const &data, int &data2) // Inputing datas
{
    cout << "Please Enter your " << data << endl;
    cin >> data2;
}`  No need for `.c_str()` or to copy the string data.

Answer (score 2):

Your `int data2` variable is a variable that's local to `enterdata`. It will be destroyed once the function returns.

If you want to change the passed-in variable you want to take in a reference to the passed argument:

```
void enterdata(string data, int& data2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the value as reference when calling `enterdata()`. This is because you are expecting the value to change and then use that value later from the calling function. Passing as reference will allow you to use the variable with changed value. Not doing so will result in some default or garbage value in the variable.

So your code should change like this:

```
void enterdata(string data, int& data2) // Inputing datas       <-- note change here
{
    cout << "Please Enter your ";
    cout << data.c_str() << endl;
    cin >> data2;
}
void input1() // Saving/Creating New
{
    system("cls");
    enterdata("Mobile Number", number);
    cout << "Your number is " << number << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some recomendations to change `data2` to a reference or pointer. But there is a second, simpler method. Just return the value

```
int enterdata(string data) // Inputing datas
{
    cout << "Please Enter your ";
    cout << data.c_str() << endl;
    int data2;
    cin >> data2;
    return data2;
}
void input1() // Saving/Creating New
{
    system("cls");
    int number = enterdata("Mobile Number");
    cout << "Your number is " << number << endl;
}
```